# Quill stem bolt is covered

Tags: stem

I've just got a new bike (ordered online). It came all assemebled except for the handlebar stem (quill type) which is completely sideways. I believe I need to loosen the stem bolt and reorient it, however, the problem is that the stem bolt seems to be covered. There is a cap, I've removed the cap but I do not see the bolt. Any idea how I should fix this? Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Huh, good question. Photo is unfortunately a bit washed out because of the flash, could you retake the photo, keeping the bolt in focus, perhaps outside in daylight so the flash isn't necessary?

Comment: I added another daylight pic, not sure it is better tho. The small hole on the surface where the bolt is supposed to be (that is visible specially on the flash lighted pic) was accidentally caused by me as I played around with the screwdriver.

Comment: oh my bad, sorry, obviously it's hard to get light down there without the flash! I was hoping to see a bit better what is blocking the tool. thanks for at least humouring me

Comment: When you get a chance - the handlebar is too far left as well.  It should be even in the clamp.  **However** thats a lot of basic assembly errors.  You would be smart to get it checked completely by a competent cyclist, or someone similar, paying special attention to the usual errors like brake setup etc.   Safety !

Comment: If you tell us what kind of bike that is I'll try to find a diagram of how the stem goes together.

Comment: This is the bike: https://www.otto.de/p/performance-cityrad-6-gang-shimano-tourney-tz-500-schaltwerk-kettenschaltung-1033241121/#variationId=1033241122

Comment: I looked everywhere for information on this bike or the parts and found nothing. No manual for the bike, no brand names in the parts list (doing the best I could translating German). The site does have a support chat and a contact page. There is a brute force method to straighten the bars. Standing with the front wheel held firmly between your legs twist the handlebars to the correct position. I usually only do this when the bars are a little crooked.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed to finallly pull out the plastic plug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely scenario is the plastic cap was inserted to far. Using a drill bit slightly smaller than the access hole, slowly drill into the plastic plug. Drill just deep enough to go through the plastic when you hit the bolt head stop. Use an "O" riing pick or a dental tool to pull the plug out. If you can't raise the plug try to insert the correct size allen wrench through the hole you drilled and loosen the bolt a few turns. Tap the top of the allen wrench to loosen the wedge. Completely remove the stem. Unscrew and remove the stem bolt and push the remains of the plug out.

Comment: I would use an awl, rather than a drill bit.  Or just hold the drill bit in your hand.